# Java SWT browser per-window proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, swt

I know that,

```
OS X: All Browser instances, regardless of native renderer, automatically use OS X's global proxy settings. These settings can be changed at any time in the OS X System Preferences.
```

and the same applies to windows:

```
Windows: All Browser instances, regardless of native renderer, automatically use Windows' global proxy settings. These settings can be changed at any time in the Windows Control Panel.
```

**How would one use multiple proxies and have each SWT browser window using a different one?**
Ok, lets say it's not possible.

Can this be done in another language? Using a real browser perhaps?

Comment: Where is that information from?

Comment: @Baz http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserproxy

Comment: Patience my friend :) You've only posted your question an hour ago...

Comment: @Baz :) alright, ill be patient

Answer (score 0):

Found a [solution to this](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) if anyone is interested.

Using **HtmlUnit** allows the following functionality,

> The last WebClient constructor allows you to specify proxy server information in those cases where you need to connect through one.

I am still open to other alternatives if anyone has one.